# How to unpack the fields with multiple values into rows using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am new to python pandas and facing this issue

```
Year, Category,      Law,     col_1,     col_2,   col_3,  col_4
2015, Contraception, Law_1, 'CO MO VA',   '' ,     'XY',   ''
```

Is there any way I can get this:

```
Year, Category,      Law,    state, stage
2015, Contraception, Law_1,   CO,   col_1
2015, Contraception, Law_1,   MO,   col_1
2015, Contraception, Law_1,   VA,   col_1
2015, Contraception, Law_1,   XY,   col_3
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation why the line with state=`XY` has stage=`col_2`. Shouldn't that be `col_3` according to the input?

Comment: @StefanScheller It was a typo, just edited it.

Comment: @RichieV - better if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.melt(frame=data, id_vars=data.columns[:3], value_name='State',var_name='Stage')  

df.State = df.State.str.split()
df = df.explode('State')

df.dropna(subset = ["State"], inplace=True)
```

- Make sure you to have pandas`0.25.0` as explode is supported in latest version only.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[:3], var_name='stage', value_name='state')
df.stage = df.stage.str.split(' ')
df = df.explode('state')
```

Comment: I got following traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danishprakash/Documents/test_chan.py", line 6, in <module>
    var_name='stage', value_name='state')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6094, in melt
    col_level=col_level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/melt.py", line 48, in melt
    "".format(missing=list(missing)))
KeyError: "The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['Category']"
```

Comment: Didn't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danishprakash/Documents/test_chan.py", line 7, in <module>
    df = df.explode('stage')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html?highlight=explode#pandas.DataFrame.explode

Comment: import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('blah.csv')
df = df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[:3], var_name='stage', value_name='state')

df.stage = df.stage.str.split(' ')
print(df)
# df = df.explode('stage')

Comment: This is what I was trying, I think the problem is with " " in state columns.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.